# UITableView which leads to another table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, dynamic

Hi I have programmed a `UITableView` which leads to another table view. Both views are dynamic and my first `tableview` has three cells Kid 1, Kid 2, Kid 3. They lead to the same table view which has four cells (Behavior, sports, studies, discipline) but kid 1 would have different table view cells recorded in core data. How can I accomplish this.

Comment: Pass the appropriate data (such as a key or user id) to the 2nd table view controller.

Comment: Yes. As rmaddy said, pass data to second view controller and reload tableview data.

Comment: Sorry but from Behavior it goes to another tableview which would run on core data for only one kid